# Google Analytics - enhanced attribution links with unigue IDs have inconsistent clicks data

Tags: google-analytics

I have a page with 4 links with 4 unigue ids linking to the same destination page. For example:

```
<a id="link1" href="abc.html">
<a id="link2" href="abc.html">
<a id="link3" href="abc.html">
<a id="link4" href="abc.html">
```

In-Page Analytics shows link1 has 30 clicks, link2 has 12-15 clicks, link3 has 8-11 clicks, and link4 has 3-6 clicks. It does not make sense for me that link1 does not have a range while all other 3 do, or vice versa.

Does anybody have the same issue?